# How to remove a specific row in dataset?

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress

I  have a gridview that is populated by a dataset and I want to remove the specfic item that the user selected in the gridview..

How I am able to remove the selected item?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a devexpress gridview...I tried to get the selected row in gridview and delete the row in datatable base on the number of the selected row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you need to set a primary column in the datatable.

then you can try this code:

```
Dim xID as string = "S-0001"
oProspectusContent.Tables("CourseList").Rows.Find(xID).Delete()
oProspectusContent.Tables("CourseList").AcceptChanges()
```

`oProspectusContent` => is the name of the dataset